# Как программно реализовать внутреннюю обводку Bitmap на Андроид?

Tags: android, java, canvas, bitmap

Всем добрый день!

Необходимо произвести программную обводку Bitmap, как представленно на рисунках ниже:

До:

[image]

После:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
<shape android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#ceb623" />
    <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="@android:color/black" />
    <corners android:radius="5dp" />
</shape>
```

Comment: Вы наверное неправильно поняли мой вопрос. Я имею ввиду, что есть какое либо изображение(например с SD карты), и надо ему программно задать обводку!

Comment: Тогда используйте `LayerDrawable`.